# Различия OAuth и OpenID

Tags: авторизация, oauth, аутентификация, oauth2, openid

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем отличаются OAuth и OpenID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **OpenID** позволяет сайту удостовериться, что его пользователь владеет
>   неким персональным URL (своим сайтом, блогом, профилем). Этого факта
>   достаточно для того, чтобы использовать уникальный URL для узнавания
>   того же самого пользователя в следующий раз. И всё. Все остальные вещи
>   — заведение аккаунта, получение email'а и других данных, разрешение
>   какой-то активности на сайте — остаётся на усмотрение сайта. Другими
>   словами, OpenID — это чистая аутентификация: вы знаете, кто к вам
>   пришёл, но вольны делать с этим знанием всё, что угодно.

---

> **OAuth** позволяет программе (на вебе или локальной) получить от
>   пользователя права на использование какого-то конкретного API. Права
>   обозначаются токеном, свойства которого никак не определены: он может
>   быть одинаковым для разных пользователей, может быть разным для одного
>   в разное время. Всё, что гарантируется — это что программа в обмен на
>   токен сможет выполнять какие-то действия на каком-то сервисе. Другими
>   словами, OAuth — это чистая авторизация: вы обладаете конкретными
>   правами, но не можете в общем случае по ним определить, кому они
>   принадлежат.

---

> Аналогия. **OpenID** — это ваш паспорт: он говорит, кто вы, но что он
>   даёт, зависит от места, куда вы с ним пришли. **OAuth** — ключи от
>   вашей машины: с ними можно ездить на вашей машине, даже не зная, как
>   вас зовут.

[Разница между OpenID и OAuth - Иван Сагалаев](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/07/14/openid-oauth-difference/)